# Android cordova scroll event not firing

Tags: android, jquery, angularjs, cordova, scroll

I am developing an android app with the cordova framework and I want to change the background color of my header panel depending on the scroll position. The problem is that the scroll event never get fired, neither in my emulator nor on the device.

An attempt with Angular:

```
app.directive("scroll", function ($document) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                console.log("scroll initiated");
                $document.bind('scroll', function () {
                    console.log("scrolling ...");
                });
            }
        };
    })
```

An attempt with jQuery:
​

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        console.log('scrolling ...');
    });
}
```

I also implemented this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cwwz75oa/1/) example in my app, but it didn't work ...

Can anyone help me to solve my problem ?

Comment: Please read the documentation! You have to wait for the cordova deviceready event.

Comment: `function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

function onDeviceReady() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(window).on('scroll', function () {
            console.log('scrolling ...');
        })
    });
}` 

It's still not working.

Comment: You likely want the [Statusbar Plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-statusbar).  You also want to read [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)

Comment: @katzu, plz provide the solution if you have fixed it. (I am using custom directive way to fix a row on top while scrolling down)

Answer (score 0):

i'm on Cordova using android and with jquery i use:

```
 $(window).scroll(function() 
   {
     ...
   }
```

and it works, tell me if it worsk even for you.

Comment: i've also created a method that fetch data and dynamically create and remove elements depending from the data i load, the pain was to set well the scroll focus.

Comment: The code is working but the event is not firing anyway because of some onsen-ui css styling ... i tried to remove the css file and it worked. but i dont know exactly what css is preventing the event to fire.

Comment: the only property in css that makes me think of scrolling is overflow (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-x.asp)...but i'm not sure if it is the only one